# How to modify the content of a TextView

Tags: java, android

I was perfectly following the guide on https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity#java to create my first Android app, but the code posted there is giving me an error. Apparently there is no TextView.setText(String) method, and my code below is not compiling:

```
    package com.example.myfirstapp;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
        }

        // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(message);
    }
```

Error message: Cannot resolve symbol 'setText'

Can anyone help?

Comment: You could not have **perfectly** followed the tutorial, since you closed the onCreate method with a } bracket, and placed all other commands right into the body of the class, outside any method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Do `findViewById` and `textView.setText(message);`
inside `onCreate()` method

Try this

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

        // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (you have to put these lines into your method) :

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

        //Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(message);**   
     }
```